# Javascript RandomNumber

Tags: javascript, arraylist

I'm pretty new in JS. I hope I can ask the question clear enough. I was building or writing a js program that receives a random input and replaces the random input with the same position of the index number. I create a function that generates the random number and replaces the open boxes array's index position then moves it to the closedboxes array. The issue is that when I call the function it starts removing 2 elements from the openBoxes array instead of one each time i call the function. why is this happening?

```
let openBoxes = ["box1", "box2", "box3", "box4", "box5", "box6", "box7", "box8", "box9", "box10", "box11"]
let closedBoxes = []

function randomlySelect() {
    let randomBox = Math.floor(Math.random() * openBoxes.length + 1)

    let moveIndex = openBoxes.splice(randomBox, 1) // remove specific index depending on the random number
    closedBoxes.push(moveIndex) // send the element to the closedBox array
    openBoxes.pop(moveIndex) // removes the element from the openBoxArray
    console.log(openBoxes)
    console.log(closedBoxes)
}

randomlySelect()
randomlySelect()
randomlySelect()
```

the output is:

```
(9) ["box1", "box2", "box3", "box4", "box6", "box7", "box8", "box9", "box10"] [Array(1)]

(7) ["box1", "box2", "box3", "box4", "box6", "box7", "box9"] [Array(1), Array(1)]

(5) ["box1", "box3", "box4", "box6", "box7"]
(3) [Array(1), Array(1), Array(1)]
```

Appreciate the help. thank you in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1)** The random number should be

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * openBoxes.length);
```

Adding one to it will select the number next to the last element. i.e `11`

**2)** [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) array removes the element from the source array, You don't have to use `pop`.

> The splice() method changes the contents of an array by `removing` or
> `replacing` existing elements and/or `adding` new elements `in place` - MDN

**3)**[pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) doesn't take any argument and always remove an element from the last.

> The pop() method removes the last element from an array and returns
> that element. - MDN

```js
let openBoxes = [
  "box1",
  "box2",
  "box3",
  "box4",
  "box5",
  "box6",
  "box7",
  "box8",
  "box9",
  "box10",
  "box11",
];
let closedBoxes = [];

function randomlySelect() {
  let randomBox = Math.floor(Math.random() * openBoxes.length);

  let moveIndex = openBoxes.splice(randomBox, 1); // remove specific index depending on the random number
  closedBoxes.push(moveIndex); // send the element to the closedBox array

  console.log(openBoxes);
  console.log(closedBoxes);
}

randomlySelect();
randomlySelect();
randomlySelect();
```